# Can I access a node server by other computers using hostname?

Tags: node.js

I have a pretty simple node server and I can access it using ip address from other computers, but I would like to use computer hostname instead.  Is there a way to do this? I can get to it on the machine that is running the server with hostname but not from others.

what i'm using right now -

```
server.listen(port, '10.10.95.122', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return;
    }

    console.log('server listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

i've tried the same code with hostname where the ip is but only works on the local machine.

Comment: Yes it does work by hostname, as for why it isn't for you, I couldn't tell you

Comment: Do you have the hostname in the DNS?  Because if you request it as a connection it doesn't lookup by hostname but rather by dns entry.  You can get around this by specifying it in the hosts file of your operating system or by adding a local network dns server.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean the hostname in the DNS. Is this something I would add in the dns settings for the connection?  I've also tried listening on '0.0.0.0'. Still only works for using the ipaddress and then hostname on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your computer to be able to resolve the IP from the hostname, you either have to add it to your hosts file, with this line :

`10.10.95.122  yourhostname`

**For Windows** the hosts file is in `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

**For OS X and Unix systems** it's (by default) in `/etc/hosts`

Otherwise you need to have it added to DNS servers, which means buying the domain and using the control panel of your domain provider to make it point to this IP.